# How to get date and time from server

Tags: php, datetime

I want to retrieve date and time from server and according to it do some thing. For this I used following code:

```
$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];

$current_date = "$date/$month/$year == $hour:$min:$sec";
```

This code returns proper date but problem is that what I see in my cpanel(server time) is diff. than what I get from code. In cpanel time is CDT while from code it is showing UTC which I reconfirm using following code

```
<?php echo date("r == e"); ?>
```

Why this is happening and what changes I have to do in my code so that I can get proper server time.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You should [set the timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to the one of the [timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) you want.

```
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT

$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];

$current_date = "$date/$month/$year == $hour:$min:$sec";
```

Or a much shorter version:

```
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // CDT

$current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this -

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$timestamp = time();
$date_time = date("d-m-Y (D) H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo "Current date and local time on this server is $date_time";
?>
```

Comment: AFAIK $date_time has to be outside of the string ?

Comment: You can write php variable between double quotes and will you get proper results but if you use between single quotes then result will be same variable name.

Answer (score 5):

**No** need to use `date_default_timezone_set` for the whole script, just specify the `timezone` you want with a DateTime object:

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));    // Another way
echo $now->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"); // something like "2015-02-11T06:16:47+0100" (ISO 8601)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the timezone, cf http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score -1):

For enable PHP Extension intl , follow the Steps..

1. Open the xampp/php/php.ini file in any editor.
2. Search ";extension=php_intl.dll"
3. kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; ) Like : ;extension=php_intl.dll. to.
   extension=php_intl.dll.
4. Save the xampp/php/php.ini file.
5. Restart your xampp/wamp.

Answer (score -2):

You should set the timezone to the one of the timezones you want. let set the Indian timezone

```
// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];

$current_date = "$date/$month/$year == $hour:$min:$sec";
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the "system( string $command[, int &$return_var] ) : string" function. For Windows system( "time" );, system( "time > output.txt" ); to put the response in the output.txt file. If you plan on deploying your website on someone else's server, then you may not want to hardcode the server time, as the server may move to an unknown timezone. Then it may be best to set the default time zone in the php.ini file. I use Hostinger and they allow you to configure that php.ini value.