# PHP - Servertime and php date() is not the same

Tags: php, time

In my WHM my server time is currently *02:19* - but when I print the time in PHP, this is the time it shows: *06:19*

I tried to run `phpinfo();` this is what it gave me:

```
date.timezone   UTC UTC
```

I am printing the time in PHP like this:

```
<?php echo date("H:i"); ?>
```

Why isn't the PHP date the same as the server time?

Comment: Maybe it's because the server where your site is hosted is in different country.

Comment: @JohnLouieDelaCruz But shouldn't PHP be according to the server, where it's hosted?

Comment: What is the current time there now? is the time in your WHM is correct or in your php?

Comment: Neither. My local time is 08:32 right now - so 2 hours different from the PHP time. Although, I wish PHP to be after my server time (which is 02:32 right now)

Comment: You have to set your timezome http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621572/how-to-get-date-and-time-from-server